# How to delete duplicate emails from a database having over 100k records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of around 126K entries, It has many entries having duplicate emails. I want to delete all the entries with duplicate ones and just the keep the one that was created earliest.

I tried using the following query but it takes forever and maxes out my server bandwidth.

Can anyone help?

```
DELETE n1 FROM table n1, table n2 WHERE n1.ID > n2.ID AND n1.email = n2.email
```

**Database Specifications**

1. PhpMyAdmin Version information: 3.5.3
2. Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
3. Software: MySQL
4. Software version: 5.0.67-community - MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
5. Protocol version: 10
6. Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can create a temporary table with unique emails and after delete all the email whose are more than once in the database .

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tab_temp
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY email;
```

Then

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM tab_temp );
```

With that you can delete those that are repeated

Comment: `1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`


I get this error when I run the second query.